# status of reachabilityForLocalWiFi is ReachableViaWWAN while on WIFI?

Tags: ipad, wifi, reachability, wwan

I need to detect if the device is connected to WIFI:

```
reach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
```

but the status is WWAN when I connect to WIFI on iPad, and there is no SIM inserted, I am about to test the status WITH a SIM.

Does anyone know the reason?

edit:

Just tried with a SIM card, it is still recognised as ReachableViaWWAN, but the actual connection is via 3G(the server only allows 3G connection, WIFI will fail), so I guess the Reachability may vary over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, the Reachability class I used is part of ASIHTTPRequest, which is a modified version, and it is modified in a way that a method is re-written but old method(with the same signature) is not removed, this does not make trouble(ie new method is called) until I created a static library for 3RD party libraries used in the project, which links the method declaration with the old method that does not fit into the modified framework of Reachability.

Answer (score 1):

Reachability *reachability   = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    BOOL remoteHostStatus        = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

```
if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi || remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)

{
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict                       =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:textFieldUserName.text,@"email",textFieldpass.text,@"password", nil];
    objApp.responseData      = [[NSMutableData data]init];
    objApp.request           = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login",mainUrl]]];
    NSData * requestBodyData                        =   [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
    objApp.request.HTTPMethod=     @"POST";
    [objApp.request setHTTPBody:requestBodyData];


    [objApp.request setTimeoutInterval:8.0f];
    // Create url connection and fire request
    objApp.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:objApp.request delegate:self];
}
else
{
    [objApp alertViewFromApp:@"check internet connection of device"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:-**

**import SystemConfiguration**

**Step 2:-**

```
 //MARK:- Internet available or Not
public  static  func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
    }
    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
    let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

**Step 3:-**

```
 if Global.isConnectedToNetwork() {
```

}